# Xamarin.iOS PeformSegue Not Working with Async/Await

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, async-await

So I’m working with Xamarin.iOS and calling an api using async/await. I seem to have encountered a situation that i can’t seem to get past.

I have a button TouchUpInside event that has an async handler and inside the handler i call PerformSegue when a certain event is triggered but that doesn’t work. I can see in the output window that multiple threads are being created and all other lines get executed as expected however the action to PerformSegue is hit and it remains on the same ViewController. I then read on Xamarin tutorial on [working with threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/ios-ui/ui-thread) where it says

> If an async method is called from a background thread (not the main UI
>   thread) then InvokeOnMainThread would still be required.

that also doesn't work.

on the other hand if I remove the async/await from my code and call PerformSegue in the handler then the code works as expected.

Can someone help with a resolution to this situation and a reason why this happens. Thanks

Here' the simplified version of the code:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
       base.ViewDidLoad();

       searchButton.TouchUpInside += SearchButton_TouchUpInside;
} 
async private void SearchButton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
       {
          {"searchText", "abc" }
       };

       searchItemsResult = await client.InvokeApiAsync<items>("search/searchitems", HttpMethod.Get, dictionary);

       if (searchItemsResult != null)
       {
          //InvokeOnMainThread(() =>   //doesn't work with this
          //{
              //tried and doe work with this either
              //DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => 
              //{
                    //doesn't push to new ViewController
                    this.PerformSegue("vC2Segue", this); 
               //});
               //});
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the last line is being called? I would bet that it is never executed, or that there is no vC2Segue. But just this above should work so the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: 1.Check if searchItemsResult == null? 2. Add a breakPoint to check if this.PerformSegue("vC2Segue", this); executed. 3. Add a timeout to your http request.

Comment: @IvanIčin I am certain that the line to PerformSegue gets called and I can also confirm that vC2Segue exists. As I mentioned async from the method and the await call to the api the PerformSegue pushes to the next viewcontroller

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT searchItemsResult == null is false. this.PerformSegue("vC2Segue", this) is hit but then doesn't push to other viewcontroller. Can you share your thoughts on why i should add a timeout for the http request? I ask because i can see that searchItemsResult contains 1 "items" in the debugger and then goes too this.PerformSegue.

Comment: Would it work if you change the await code to await Task.Delay(3000);? I ask you to add a timeout to make sure the PerformSegue did hit after call api. Can you provide a sample with the simplest code to reproduce the problem? I can't reproduce it on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT it works when i replace the await client.InvokeApiAsyc... with await Task.Delay(3000)

Comment: So the problem is in your client.InvokeApiAsyn method?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I'm not so sure. The client is a standard Azure mobileserviceclient. and the call above actually works as "searchitemsResult" contains data when i hit if(searchItemsResult != null)....its just the call to PerformSegue that isn't behaving as it should.
I may have narrowed it down but I still don't understand why its happening. I replaced the manual segue with an an automatic segue in storyboard by dragging  between the searchbutton and VC2 and leaving the code as it is above and it works.

Comment: Did you manage to get any further with this? I believe I have encountered something similar.